# Making timestamp out of just characters in R

Tags: r, timestamp

I tried to make a recognized timestamp out of this date:

```
a <- VN 20190307
a <-gsub("\\D", "", a) ##Removed VN
as.POSIXct(a, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

However, i get a NA. The outcome should be something like 2019-03-07

Side note: This is only a part of a confidential dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value `"VN"` is fixed you can use `as.Date` as -

```
a <- "VN 20190307"
as.Date(a, 'VN %Y%m%d')
#[1] "2019-03-07"
```

If `"VN"` is not fixed you can continue your approach with `gsub` and then use `as.Date`.

```
as.Date(gsub('\\D', '', a), '%Y%m%d')
#[1] "2019-03-07"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use directly `ymd` function from `lubridate` package:

```
a <- 'VN 20190307'
lubridate::ymd(a)
#"2019-03-07"
```